# Print a binary tree, level by level, following some rules

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a hard task to do and need your help.

I need print a binary tree follow this rules:
Print level by level without using matrix;
Has to print from the root and you never should edit the lines after you printed;
the number cannot be at the same column that any other.
This is the format:

```
              |----10----|
           |--13--|      1---|
           15    11          0
```

Its a not AVL-tree. Has to work on any size of tree.

this is what I have so far:

```
public String printTree() {
    if (getAltura() == -1) { //See if the tree is empty
        return "Arvore Vazia";
    }
    if (getAltura() == 0) { //Check if only have one node in the tree;
        return raiz.chave + "";
    }
    return printTree0();
}

private String printTree0() {
    String arvore = ""; //String with the binary tree
    //String linha = ""; 
    int espaco = 0; //That was what I try to use to put the number under the "|" character
    //int altura = 0;
    Queue<Nodo> q = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= getAltura(); i++) {
        q.addAll(getNivel(i));
    }

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Nodo n = q.remove();
        if (n.direito == null && n.esquerdo == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < espaco; i++) {
                arvore += " ";
            }
        }
        if (n.esquerdo != null) { //Check if this node has a left son.
            int subarvores = tamanhoSubarvores(n.esquerdo); //Do the math to see how many ASCII character are need to put in this side of the tree.
            for (int i = 0; i < subarvores; i++) {
                arvore += " ";
                espaco++;
            }
            arvore += "|";
            for (int i = 0; i < subarvores; i++) {
                arvore += "-";
            }
        }
        arvore += n.chave;
        if (n.direito != null) { //Check if this node has a right son.
            int subarvores = tamanhoSubarvores(n.direito); //Do the math to see how many ASCII character are need to put in this side of the tree.
            for (int i = 0; i < subarvores; i++) {
                arvore += "-";
            }
            arvore += "|";
            for (int i = 0; i < subarvores; i++) {
                arvore += " ";
            }
        }

        arvore += "\n";

    }

    return arvore;

}

private int tamanhoSubarvores(Nodo nodo) {
    int size = 0;
    for (Nodo n : getNivel(nodo.altura, nodo)) {
        size += Integer.toString(n.chave).length();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'll get more luck if you post some of your attempts.

Comment: what's the input format?

Comment: What specific question are you asking? What work have you done so far? Have you read the stackoverflow introduction at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Comment: There is no input format, the tree is inicializate on the main method.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is called a [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Given that an `AVL tree` only differs from a normal `Binary Search Tree` during the addition or removal of an element, the algorithm logic for the BF-Search listed in wiki link above should apply.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Until now I only print the first level and coudnt go deeper on the tree.